# Getting a paid podcast onto Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I subscribe to a podcast that I pay for, and I am given a personalized URL which I originally plugged into the Zune software and it worked great.  Now I have WP8, and I am trying to get the podcast into this new system.  Problem is, there is no apparent way to put the URL in so that it syncs with the source.

Is there a way that I am unaware of?

The URL looks like this:

http://www.medvedmedhead.com/category/radio-show/podcast/?feedkey=06fa40094e5d0563dcc862ecxxxxxxxx

There is no way to insert the URL into the store.  Putting it into IE only gets me the Xml.  Apparently I can use iTunes to download the podcast.  I might be able to sneak it onto the phone through iTunes.  I am checking on this.

Comment: More information about the url is required.  Have you asked the product of the podcast?  There is nothing special about `Zune` that would prevent you from either using podcasting software on phone itself to download it instead.  Please clarify what you did earlier, you make it sound, like you had a WP7 phone.

Answer (score 0):

I usually have Zune download it on the PC and then sync that with the phone. Right click on the Podcast in Zune and select Series Settings.

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is how I did for WP7.  Zune does not interact with WP8.  That's my problem.

Comment: Wasn't aware WP8 and Zune weren't paired like WP7 and Zune are. Seems WP8 has new sync software and it is a regression (lots of complaints around the web).